# schedule algorithm for minimal contact time and group size for my child's daycare

Tags: algorithm, optimization, mathematical-optimization, operations-research

Given the new legal regulations due to covid-19 the daycare of my child and all involved parents are overwhelmed and we need to come up with a schedule of when which child can be cared for.

Given the demanded care time per child (s. below), We need an algorithm to optimize the following:

1. **Minimal total contacts / fixed groups**. If children meet, it is best if they stay in that group and do not see children of other groups.
2. While point 1 is more important, the 2nd prio would be to reduce the **size per group** or maybe it should be phrased as **minimal count of different children met per child**
3. Even less important: reduce **total contact time**.

(Maybe there are other requirements, that I overlooked?)

The demands are of following nature (Timespan and type) :

| Case | Child | Timespan | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (1) Fixed time, Required | 1 | Monday, 8:30 - 13:00 | Required |
| (2) Fixed time, nice to have | 1 | Tuesday, 8:30 - 13:00 | Nice to have |
| (see (1)) | 1 | Tuesday, 13:00 - 16:00 | Required |
| (see (1)) | 1 | Thursday, 8:30 - 13:00 | Required |
| (see (1)) | 2 | Monday 8:30 - 13:00 | Required |
| (3) Flexibel date, required | 2 | Any 2 other days 8:30 - 13:00 | Required |
| (4) Flexibel date, nice to have | 2 | Any day 13:00 - 16:00 | Nice to have |
| (5) Flexibel datetime, Required | 3 | 3 hours | Required |
| (6) Flexibel datetime, Nice to have | 3 | 3 additional hours | Nice to have |
|  | ... | ... | ... |

- Required = The child must have daycare
- Nice to have = daycare is demanded but not required. E.g. if child 1 meets child 2 and 3 on Monday and Thursday, it would be fine to meet the same children on Tuesday morning as well, but if it is a completely different group of children than this would not make sense.
- All provided timespans must stay in one continuous piece (meaning that 3 hours cannot be split up into multiple slots).

**Additional Information**

- There is only one room available.
- There are 15 children in total.
- If a solution is much better than the other it is ok-ish to violate "Required" demands for a few cases. We might be able to find a different solution for the parents in few situations. The algorithm should hence contain a parameter like `maxAllowedViolations` - let's say it's `3` and it should compare how much the solution is better than without the errors.
- The demand is provided per week and might change from week to week. I only know the demand one week in advance. The ideal grouping hence might change per week, but it might be better to respect the grouping of the last week as a guidance, because corona has about 7 to 10 days of incubation time.
- The caregivers are tested for covid-19 twice a week, the children are not.

I do not care in which language or pseudo-code-ish way the algorithm is, but I will try to implement the algorithm in a web-based format so other daycare centers can use it as well.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? For a single daycare facility you can most likely get away with a brut force approach.

Comment: I am not sure how to approach the problem. I thought of a linear optimization algorithm but I do not know a lot about algorithms and hence I am not sure which are even applicable.

Comment: You have three steps of optimization here. If you choose linear programming, either you can build three models that are called one after the other, either you can choose to make one model and modulate your different variables of the optimization function